Kibana security must be enabled to use Fleet - docker-compose
I'm trying to setup apm on my kibana but have problem with security.
Kibana security must be enabled to use Fleet when i try to add integration to kibana.
part of my docker-compose.tml
    elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.10.3
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
        - discovery.type=single-node
        - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms4600m -Xmx4600m"
        - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ports:
        - 9200:9200
        - 9300:9300
    volumes:
        - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
        - mongors-network
    mem_limit: "5000M"
kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.10.3
    ports:
        - "5601:5601"
    networks:
        - mongors-network
    environment:
        - XPACK_ENCRYPTEDSAVEDOBJECTS_ENCRYPTIONKEY=[key]
        - XPACK_REPORTING_ENCRYPTIONKEY=[key]
        - XPACK_SECURITY_ENCRYPTIONKEY=[key]
        - xpack.security.enabled=true
    depends_on:
        - elasticsearch
apm-server:
    image: docker.elastic.co/apm/apm-server:8.10.3
    environment:
      OUTPUT_ELASTICSEARCH_ENABLED: "true"
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: "http://elasticsearch:9200"
    ports:
      - "8200:8200"
    networks:
      - mongors-network

What am I missing here?
Apm server seems to work fine because in my .net application I'm able to put some logs so there is problem on kibana/elastic side but cannot find working solution.
Thanks in advance
